# High # of sockets in TIME-WAIT state, server unresponsive at load

Tags: nginx, node.js, socket, cloudflare, time-wait

Our app became unresponsive at high loads, with longer wait times. Process usage was abnormally low (~15% CPU utilisation per process, our app runs on 8 processes).

Nginx error log output showed a number of these:

```
2014/12/04 03:39:31 [crit] 24383#0: *2008067 connect() to 127.0.0.1:4567 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address) while connecting to upstream, client: 108.162.246.229, server: example.org, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1417682366937-11501 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4567/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1417682366937-11501", host: "example.org", referrer: "https://example.org/unread"
```

#### What I saw

- Output of `ss -tan | grep TIME-WAIT | wc -l` was somewhere in the neighbourhood of 30,000, ouch!
- The app would be responsive, and then:

  - All processes would suddenly drop down to near 0 CPU usage
  - App would become unresponsive
  - After ~30 seconds, app would be back up, repeat ad infinitum

---

Needed to get the app up, so band-aid solution:

- `echo 28000 65535 > ip_local_port_range` (MongoDB runs on 27101 so I picked a lower limit above that)
- `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse`
- `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle`

This reduced the # of sockets in `TIME-WAIT` state to a more managable ~400.

---

Here's a snippet of `ss -tan | grep TIME-WAIT`:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:29993            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:28522            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:29055            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:31849            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:32744            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:28304            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:34858            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:36707            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:34756            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0            104.131.91.122:443          108.162.250.6:55549 
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:32629            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:34544            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:34732            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:33820            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:33609            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:34504            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:32463            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:35089            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:30003            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0            104.131.91.122:443         199.27.128.100:36383 
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:33040            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:34038            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:28096            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:29541            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:30022            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:31375            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:29827            127.0.0.1:4567  
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:29334            127.0.0.1:4567
```

My questions:

- A lot of these are from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1, is this normal? Shouldn't the peer addresses all be from external IPs?

  - Our Node.js app is behind nginx proxy, behind CloudFlare DNS, this limits the number of unique inbound IP addresses, could this be related?
- How do I *properly* reduce the number of sockets in `TIME-WAIT` state?
- I'm positive we don't have 3000 unique socket connections **per second**, is something misconfigured on our end and opening up hundreds of sockets when it should be opening one?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: The local->local connection is normal since nginx is proxying to your node.js app (so it has to open a TCP connection to it). Note that you can use a lower range even if Mongo is listening on one since the kernel won't try to use it.

Comment: Consider [using a UNIX domain socket](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7045614/1068283) instead of a TCP listener in your node.js app.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, good to know. Will give it a shot and report back @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I did more research and read this [very excellent guide](https://engineering.gosquared.com/optimising-nginx-node-js-and-networking-for-heavy-workloads) on scaling Node apps behind an nginx proxy.

The major difference came when I added the `keepalive` parameter to the `upstream` block in nginx. As it turns out, nginx workers don't cache incoming connections and re-use them, causing many thousands of new connections to be created (esp. w/ socket.io handshakes and such)

@MichaelHampton's suggestion of using a unix domain socket would also resolve this quite well.